# install cordova failed with node.js command prompt

Tags: node.js, cordova

[image]

what is my problem? is it successfully installed or failed? It doesn't seem right for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordova was installed successfully. You are looking at the dependency tree, so don't worry.

Bear in mind that you have installed the CLI tools. You have to actually create a cordova project with the command before you will see a cordova project.

```
cordova create <Your project name>
```